# Auto correction behaviour on XAML bound datetime objects since .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

While bringing an application from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 I've run into this peculiar issue.

(culture is nl-BE)

I bind a TextBox like this (in XAML) to a DateTime value with an UpdateSourceTrigger on PropertyChanged (LostFocus works as expected but as-you-type validation is required):

```
<TextBox Height="23" Margin="146,0,105,97.04" Name="txb_Geboortedatum" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Geboortedatum" StringFormat="d" 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Now when the contents of this textbox is (for example) **10/12/2000** and I want to edit it to be **09/03/1981** some obnoxious **auto-correction occurs** when i put the cursor at the end of 2000 and start 'backspacing' away the year value (when only the first digit ('2') of '2000' is left the value automatically - including cursor jump - changes to 2002 again). Can I disable this auto-correction?

I can't seem to find what specifically introduced this behaviour. The same 'problem' also occurs with `FormatString=c` for currency values.

What I've tried so far:

1. Changing the FormatString to something more explicit like `{0}{dd/MM/yyyy}` (same problem: starts auto-correcting when there are 2 digits for year left).
2. Disabling the following snippet I've added to my App.xaml.cs:

   ```
   FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
       typeof(FrameworkElement), 
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
           CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
   ```

The reasoning for this snippet to be included in the first place: [have a look at this link](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/03/18/getting-a-wpf-application-to-pick-up-the-correct-regional.aspx).

Am i missing something obvious here? I can't reproduce this in 3.5. Do I really have to roll my own ValueConverters for getting this to work properly? That looks like a step back from `StringFormat` which was introduced in 3.5 sp 1.

Output from `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns('d')` does looks slightly different, nothing that would immediately explain the behaviour though (probably unrelated):

```
.NET 3.5        .NET 4.0

d/MM/yyyy       d/MM/yyyy
d/MM/yy         d/MM/yy
dd-MM-yy        dd-MM-yy
dd.MM.yy        dd.MM.yy
yyyy-MM-dd      dd.MMM.yyyy
                yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: ~Related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f4e5a910-456d-455b-b5fd-62e5282a7562 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/afc5bb80-be70-4d6f-8713-56e76af5394e Is there really no easy fix for this?

Comment: ~Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852106/strange-problem-with-wpf-textbox-stringformat-cursor-moves-back (although no real fix here either - the answer just says 'revert to lostfocus instead of propertychanged' but that's not really what I need). It does work in 3.5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using something like this for now, but I would be extremely interested in other approaches for solving the problem above:

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) { return ""; }
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            return dt.ToShortDateString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, 
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.ToString().Trim().Length==0) { return null; }
        string frmt = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.ToString(), frmt, 
                                   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            return dt;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this behavior is 'normal' if you auto-correct on PropertyChanged.
When you start backspacing, the value passed to the DateTime constructor is :

Screen >> DateTime ( '**|**' is the cursor placement **before each backspace**)

```
10-12-2000| >> DateTime(200,12,10) >> 10-12-0200

10-12-020|0 >> DateTime(020,12,10) >> 10-12-020 

10-12-00|20  >> DateTime(020,12,10) >> 10-12-020 

10-12-0|20 >> DateTime(20,12,10) >> 10-12-2020
```

(I think this can vary with your culture because of the **yy-mm-dd** string format)

tough i dont quite get why new DateTime(20,12,10) guive the year 2020 for me on the textbox. When i use DateTime.Parse(20,12,10) it guive me 2012-10-20 (yyyy-mm-dd). Ther must be some kind of automatique conversion or parsing that we dont have control over unless we use a custom ValueConvertor

**I think a custom converter is a good way to go if you absolutly need 'as-you-type validation'**, else OnLostFocus works well as you said.

Btw, my culture is en-US

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DatePicker control?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've thought about this, and this could indeed be an alternative for the 'DateTime' parsing textbox although it does not solve similar StringFormat / PropertyChanged problems with currency I'm also experiencing... I find it really strange that I should roll my own ValueConverters for getting this to work propertly (that's a step back from StringFormat which was introduced in 3.5sp1).

Comment: But why do you have to use StringFormat, DatePicker already displays everything correctly based on UI Culture.