# WPF TextBox behaving poorly while deleting decimals using backspace button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to WPF and currently doing a basic project in accounting which deals with decimal values. I have issue while deleting the decimal values using the backspace key.

At first i have typed only 10 digits but while trying to delete from last digit lets say from (____.00) i couldn't able to delete. it was deleting two 0's and adding two 0's again.

This issue happens only when i type more than 10 digits.

Image 1:
https://ibb.co/mghcsn
Image 2:
https://ibb.co/ghr3Xn

```
//textbox code
<TextBox x:Name="txtTax2Percent" Tag="{x:Static r:Resources.Tax2Percent}" Text="{Binding Path=Tax2Percent, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" TabIndex="1" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox"></TextBox>

//Model with notify property changed
    [Display(Name = "Tax2 Percent")]
    [Range(0.00, 100.00)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public decimal Tax2Percent
    {
        get { return _tax2percent; }
        set
        {
            _tax2percent = value;
            ValidateProperty(value);
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Tax2Percent));
        }
    }

//Number Validation
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
```

Comment: what's ValidateProperty doing?

Comment: BTW, you are creating a new Regex for every typed key... If the Regex is always the same, declare it on the class...

Comment: I used the validation for checking null entries and for notifying changes to data model.

Comment: even after removing regex i am still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Text="{Binding Path=Tax2Percent, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

The problem here is everytime you type a character it trigger the set {} and propertychanged, which causes the textbox to update and trigger **StringFormat=N2**, which causes it to format the decimal string.

The only solution i can think of right now is change the UpdateSourceTrigger to

```
UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus //so that it only trigger the update once the textbox lost focus
//the validation will only trigger once it lost focus, which is better then sudden lag when
//typing due to validation fail.
```

Comment: Your suggestion was working but I need the formatting to happen on the flow...is it possible.

Comment: Yep, restore the PropertyChanged instead of LostFocus. Add a Delay like in <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Delay=500}"/>

Comment: @Paventhan can you clarify more on reason/cases you need the formatting to happen on the flow? so that i can design a better solution for u

Comment: @pengMiao thank you for the response, my project is a kind of inventory management which also deals with the product prices. Though validation works well, i would like my UI to be good. Since i am not a professional i am using google and stackoverflow to learn and develop my WPF project. It would be nice if you help me out with this issue.

Comment: @Paventhan hard, because it is a misbehavior issue of textbox with stringformat. c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852106/strange-problem-with-wpf-textbox-stringformat-cursor-moves-back and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591172/wpf-textbox-binding-with-formatting?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think there is no way i would better use your suggestion. Thanks a lot.